# Next.js server components will cache the fetch calls always?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch-api, react-server-components

I have got a big application where I got the upmost layout that does a lot of checks and fetches for some user data and verifies it's valid, all server rendered.

The app/(dashboard)/layout.tsx file looks like this:

```
export default async function DefaultLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {

  // Fetch user data
  var userState = await fetchUserData();

  return (
    other components...
  );
}

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
```

Then I have got another server component as child of this which does another await fetchUserData() to get the userState.

The fetchUserData function is a fetch to my db with       { cache: "no-store" }
, so it shouldn't cache any data

The interesting bit is that even if I call this function 2 times, on my database it only does 1 request, so this means that Next.js will call fetch once then even if it has "no-store" during this render it won't do the fetch again?

Next.js docs say "This request should be refetched on every request." for the no-store property on a fetch call, but even if that function with the fetch is called 2 times (I have tested it with a console.log before the fetch), on my database it only logs 1 call.

Does this work on a render to render basis? If I do 1 fetch then during the current render that fetch will never be called again but instead the initial fetch data will be used? What if I wanted to fetch 2 times and get data each time?